# While loop skips switch cases and executes default

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement, case, default

The program should run calculations for different shapes as different cases nested inside a while loop. Heres the code:

```
package Lab_7;
import java.util.*;

public class compar {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner d = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean start = true;


    while(start){
        System.out.print("Would you like to start the program?: ");
        String answer1 = d.nextLine();

        switch (answer1){
            case "yes":
                System.out.println("Which shape would you like to use to compute area/perimeter?: ");
                String answer2 = d.nextLine();  

                if(answer2.equals("circle")){           
                    try{
                        System.out.print("Enter radius: ");
                        int answer3 = d.nextInt();
                        Circle c = new Circle(answer3);
                        double area = c.computeArea();
                        double perimeter = c.computePerimeter();
                        System.out.println("Area = " + area + " & perimter = " + perimeter );
                        break;                          
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println("Error!");
                        break;
                    }
                }

            case "no":
                System.out.println("Program Terminating...");
                start = false;
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("bug");
                continue;
            }
    }
    d.close();
}
```

}

However, after running the first successful run, the program should loop back to the beginning (asking the user to start the program?) but instead this happens:

```
Would you like to start the program?: yes
Which shape would you like to use to compute area/perimeter?: 
circle

Enter radius: 10

Area = 314.16 & perimter = 62.832

Would you like to start the program?: bug

Would you like to start the program?:
```

I could use a bunch of if-statements but I really need to know why after the first successful run, my program:

1. Skips all cases and executes the default statement, then loops back to the first print statement and finally waits for input?

Comment: It is becuause of this `in.nextInt();` this contains a string character `\n` So it will skip next `in.nextLine()` You want to try putting `in.nextLine()` after the `in.nextInt()`

Comment: There is a missing `break` statement at the end of `case "yes"`.

Comment: @Smit You have that completely back to front. `nextInt()` does *not* contain a newline, and will *not* skip the next `nextLine()`, so the requirement is to consume the newline by adding a `nextLine()` call. Your explanation makes no sense.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for correcting me. Appreciate your feedback. Will take note from the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter the radius, `d.nextInt()` consumes the next int, but not the new line.

After the area is computed, the `break` statement terminates the switch statement.

Then the line `String answer1 = d.nextLine()` consumes the new line that `d.nextInt()` didn't consume, which causes it to execute the default case because `answer1` was neither `"yes"` or `"no"`.

The `continue` causes the execution to go back to the start of the `while` loop, where it then waits for input again.

To fix it, add `d.nextLine()` after getting input for the radius:

```
int answer3 = d.nextInt();
d.nextLine(); //consumes the \n character
```

Also, you have to add a `break` to the end of the yes case. Otherwise, the user could enter `"yes"` and then something other than `"circle"`, and the program execution would fall through to the no case and terminate.